# Cardinality of the Mandelbrot set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the Mandelbrot set countable or of the cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$? My intuition says the latter, but I couldn't find a bijection.

Comment: The more interesting fact is that the *boundary* of the Mandelbrot set has Hausdorff dimension 2.

Answer (score 18):

$M$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ and contains the open disk of radius $\frac14$ around the origin, i.e., $M$ is "between" two sets of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, hence itself of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.